# How does refrence work $ref , x-template? attaching a common component to child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Basically i am working on a project on which users can post questions and users can also answer to those questions. A post generally has upvote, downvote and comments for example … how do i design it, So let’s say there is comment button with every answers so what i want is when i click on comment button of any answer i should be able to get all the comments of that particular answer(this is backend i am not worrying about this).just like facebook or quora’s comment system, I am just think about front end part how to i do show when user click on comment button , will $ref work in this case or i have to think of other method , approach

And also let just say i have separate table for upvote downvote(one table for both) and similary answers and questions and users table … my concern is upvotedownvote table is going to grow faster than anything (6000 upvotes means 6000 rows, i am normalizing) . In this case join four table will be costly and will make it slower what i am thinking is to join three tables except upvotes table i.e fetching answers, users name who has answered and question also from fisrt three table and then passing all ids of currently loaded answers to database to get upvote downvotes count of each answers using some lifecycle hook method what would be the best way to do that , Any help would be appriciated thank you

Comment: share some code ?

Comment: i haven't started this part, attaching comment box when user click on comment button , I dont know how to start , I want to leverage vuejs feature
 that i am not aware of, can u please give some idea? what would be best way using $ref, x-template, v-html etc?

Comment: Using v-html directive for user entered content is bad idea. And why are you joining four tables on backend for every frontend call? Create View in your database.

Comment: 4 tables users ,answers, questions upvotes downvotes count , i think i have to join 4 tables to get the data that i want to display on screen like . question title , answer of this question and user who has answered and upvotes downvotes on this answer

Comment: you are talking about cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the database size yet. 6000 rows may sound like a lot, but in reality it is a really small amount for a database. Most likely you won't encounter any performance problems at this scale and performance problems are best solved when you encounter them.

Your other question is a bit unclear what you are asking. Likely you will have something like a component that includes all the posts on the page and then a separate post component. When the user wants to view all comments you'll just send an Ajax request to the server, get an array of the comments and pass them to the post component inside v-for.

Comment: i am thinking like comment sytem to be like how facebook and quora have done … i am concerned about UI part how would i show … comment box is going to have some styling users picture and their comments i have to make a template … when user click on view comments this template should pop up with all the related comments with this particular so where do i keep this “template” and when user click on view comments then how do i attach with this particular answer

Comment: @waq for that you should use vue-router. You take the user to a new page which has its own template